# smooth minimization of piecewise linear convex function

Tags: convex-optimization

Is it possible to apply Nesterov's smooth minimization of non smooth function on a problem of the form

$$\mathop {\min }\limits_{\lambda  \in {R^m}} \mathop {\max }\limits_{\sigma  \in {{\left\{ {0,1} \right\}}^n}} a_\sigma ^T\lambda $$

where we have an oracle to calculate

$$f(\lambda ) = \mathop {\max }\limits_{\sigma  \in {{\left\{ {0,1} \right\}}^n}} a_\sigma ^T\lambda $$

and

$$\partial f\left( \lambda  \right)$$

further, $a_\sigma ^T$ is a (-1,0,1) vector depending on ${\sigma  \in {{\left\{ {0,1} \right\}}^n}}$

Thank you.

Comment: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/19583/4274.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 2):

No, I think to apply Nesterov's smoothing technique you need access to a more powerful oracle, namely to a projection oracle not just the linear oracle that you have.